# How to resolve JSON syntax errors in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I started learning rails using **'Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition'**
with
 `rails 3.2.7` and `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]`.
 When i tried to
edit an html form with

```
   <%= f.text_area :description  :rows=>6 %>
```

it returned an error

```
       /media/ashku/New Volume/RoR/depot/app/views/products/_form.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...= ( f.text_area :description  :rows=>6 );@output_buffer.safe...
```

then i tried to change the  `:rows=>6   to rows: 6` but the results where the same

Discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422771/beginner-rails-syntax) suggests it as problem with JSON

controller code is given [here](http://pastebin.com/sBQUSEKi)

so how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: This is not JSON. Instead, the other question dealt with the new JSON-style syntax for hashes introduced in Ruby 1.9. It looks a tiny bit like JSON, but is definitely not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the comma(,) after tag name ie.(:description).
So replace your tag with following and try to run..

```
<%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 6 %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma in between `:description`, and `:rows`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Better Errors" gem for debugging in development env., this is a better tool to find errors in good way. read about them from http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel?view=asciicast